DIff output between 2 directories is printing the filename instead of the content
I have a directory named v1, with following tree
v1
├── a.json
├── b.json
├── c.json
├── d.json
├── CRESTReport        # this is a directory i.e. v1/CRESTReport
│   ├── crest.json
│   ├── crest1.json
├── Servers            # this is a directory i.e. v1/Servers
│   ├── 01             # this is a directory i.e. v1/Servers/01
│       ├── 01.json  
│   ├── 02             # this is a directory i.e. v1/Servers/02
│       ├── 02.json  

Another directory named v2, also has same structure and set of files (It does not matter if there are any extra files in v2). For each .json files from v1, I need to validate if the same .json exists in v2. If it exists, I need a separate output file for diff performed on each .json file.
Have written a script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Provide full path of Config for v1 followed by v2
v1path="$1"
v2path="$2"

for v1File in $(find "$v1path" -name "*.json" -printf '%f\n')
do
    v2File=$(find "$v2path" -type f -name $v1File -printf '%f\n')
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
    echo "Doing a diff between v1 $v1File and v2 $v2File"
    diff <(find "$v1path" -name $v1File) <(find "$v2path" -name $v2File) > "${v1File}_Diff_Output"
    else
        echo "Filename $v1File Not Found in v2" > ${v1File}_Missing_In_v2"
    fi
done

the output I get in each file is:
a.json_Diff_Output
1c1
< /mnt/c/Users/mshah220/AMConfigDataComparison/v1/a.json
---
> /mnt/c/Users/mshah220/AMConfigDataComparison/v2/a.json

b.json_Diff_Output
1c1
< /mnt/c/Users/mshah220/AMConfigDataComparison/v1/b.json
---
> /mnt/c/Users/mshah220/AMConfigDataComparison/v2/b.json

crest.json_Diff_Output
1c1
< /mnt/c/Users/mshah220/AMConfigDataComparison/v1/CRESTReporter/crest.json
---
> /mnt/c/Users/mshah220/AMConfigDataComparison/v2/CRESTReporter/crest.json

Instead I want the out in each file like:
4c4
<     "amsterVersion" : "6.5.3",
---
>     "amsterVersion" : "7.3.0",

Q2) And the each missing files from v1 that is written to a new directory. How can I just write all the missing files into a single directory?

The process substitutions <(find ...) likely should be command substitutions $(find ...) - but there are many other issues with your solution

@steeldriver - Thank you. Changing to command substitution at least gave me the required output.  I am not from coding/scripting background and have just started writing, I know my script is not efficient. (for example: I am doing a repetitive find). Can you help me in correcting? Anything will be useful. If not can you list them and I will learn them.

As a starting point, copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.
